# How to get the navigation properties, for a newly modified model object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following ViewModel class:-

```
public class RackJoin{
public Rack Rack { get; set; }
public Resource Resource { get; set; }}
```

And the following Post Edit action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(RackJoin rj,FormCollection formValues)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
repository.InsertOrUpdateRack(rj.Rack, User.Identity.Name, rj.Resource.RESOURCEID);
                    repository.Save();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
 //code goes here
ViewBag.PossibleDataCenters = repository.AllDataCenter().OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
ViewBag.PossibleZones = repository.AllZone().OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
ViewBag.Products = repository.GetProducts("Rack").OrderBy(a => a.COMPONENTNAME).ToList();

            return View(rj);
 }
```

And the following view:-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.RackJoin

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Rack.RackID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Resource.RESOURCEID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Rack.timestamp)
    <div >
    <span class="f">Tag Number </span> 
   <span class="f"> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Rack.Technology.Tag, new 
        { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</span>
        </div>
        @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

But the problem I am facing is that I am unable to retrieve the Technology navigating property for the modified Rack object inside the view

```
<span class="f"> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Rack.Technology.Tag, new 
        { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</span>
```

, since I am creating a new Rack object and mark it as modified ? So how I can fix this issue.

**::EDIT::**
The repository method is :-

```
 public void InsertOrUpdateRack(Rack rack,string username,long assetid)
        {
//code goes here
// Existing entity
tms.Entry(rack).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `disabled` attribute on your input field if you want this value to be sent to the server. `readonly` should suffice and allow for the value to be sent to the server when the form is submitted:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.Rack.Technology.Tag, 
    new { @readonly = "readonly" }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i do not want to post the Tag number back to the server. My problem is different, it is that in-case the DbUpdateConcurrencyException is raised inside my action method. then inside the view i am unable to retrieve the Rack.Technology navigation property, since inside my Edit action method i am creating a new Rack object and mark it as EntityState.Modified. so my question was how i can include the Technology navigation property for the new Rack object that has been marked as modified. so that i can reference and access it ?

Comment: I guess you have to retrieve it from your database the same way you did in your GET action.

Comment: i have added the repository method that is responsible for the update action. and if i was retrieving the Rack object from the database before editing it , instead of creating a new Rack object and mark it as modified then there will be no problem ?

Comment: Dimitriv. but retrieving it from the database instead of marking it as required will break the concurrency exception..

Comment: Why would it break? The exception is already thrown. What would this modify? From what I understand you are attempting to display this value in the view. So you have to retrieve this value from somewhere if it was not present in the model initially.

Comment: No the DbUpdateConcurrencyException, will never get fired if i am retriving the object from the database prior to editing it. to force the DbUpdateConcurrencyException to fire i should create a new object mark it as modified then try to save it.